# Upgrade Mysql old password to new version

Tags: php, mysql, linux, bash, shell

This probably has been asked before. Some passwords for the users are stored in 16 bit format. Mysql has been upgraded to 5.5, but the passwords in the table remained in a 16 bit format.

A way to tell what password scheme your MySQL is using is to run this query below, it will list each user’s password length (16 or 41):

```
mysql> SELECT `User`, `Host`, Length(`Password`) FROM mysql.user;
+—————-+—————–+——————–+
| User | Host | Length(`Password`) |
+—————-+—————–+——————–+
| root | localhost | 16 |
| mary | 20.20.3.2 | 16 |
| fred | localhost | 16 |
| sally | 64.56.139.194 | 16 |
| fschmidt | 64.56.139.194 | 16 |
…
```

To change the user to having the exact same password but stored in the newer longer format, we can do this:

```
mysql> SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR ‘visitlogger’@’64.55.129.%’=PASSWORD(‘ ‘);
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Now we can verify the changes:

```
mysql> SELECT `User`, `Host`, Length(`Password`) FROM mysql.user;
+—————-+—————–+——————–+
| User | Host | Length(`Password`) |
+—————-+—————–+——————–+
| root | localhost | 41 |
| mary | 20.20.3.2 | 41 |
| fred | localhost | 41 |
| sally | 64.56.139.194 | 41 |
| fschmidt | 64.56.139.194 | 41 |
+—————-+—————–+——————–+
```

Can anyone help me figuring out a way to make this changes automatically. It will be a pain to do this manually for all my users. Thank you!

Comment: i don't understand what password length and mysql version have to do with each other

Comment: @Dagon Some time ago (as in years) MySQL's password hashing system was changed from one that produced a 16-hex-digit hash to one that produced a 41-hex-digit version. I thought all the pain of this had long gone. It seems not.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set up password to some predefined value to all users that have their password in old format, without issuing `SET PASSWORD` for each one of them, you can do

```sql
SET SESSION old_passwords=FALSE;
UPDATE mysql.user 
   SET password = PASSWORD('<some predefined value>')
 WHERE LENGTH(password) = 16;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

**Note:** before doing any updates make sure you a have solid backup. Just in case.